# как вывести текст в определенное время

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

пыталась научиться выводить текст в определенное время на *python*, но не выходит. Где я ошиблась?

```
import datetime
import sys

date_time = datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 21, 20, 0)
today = datetime.datetime.today()

print(date_time)
print(today)

while True:
    if date_time == today:
        print("выведен")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("не выведен")
```

Comment: Что именно вы хотите реализовать? Напечатать "выведен", если `date_time` == `today` или же ждать в цикле того момента, когда `today` сравняется с `date_time`? Если первое, то не нужен цикл и лучше использовать неравенство. Если второе, то `today` нужно обновлять **внутри** цикла, иначе цикл станет бесконечным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `date_time < today`, так во время выполнения цикла программа не пропустит момент времени, когда вам нужно вывести сообщение.
Дело в том что один цикл выполняется по мере исполнения всего что в нём написано, а значит время одного цикла не фиксировано.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Моя переменная *today* брала значение лишь один раз, тогда когда я добавила ее в цикл *while*, сменила `date_time == today` на `date_time > today` и переработала логику. Все стало работать верно. Всем огромное спасибо!

```
import datetime
import sys
import time

date_time = datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 22, 42, 0)
today = datetime.datetime.today()



print(date_time)
print(today)
while True:
    if date_time > today:   
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        print(today)
    else:
        print("Вышло")
        break
```